# Tauri transparent window only works when resized

Tags: css, rust, svelte, sveltekit, tauri

I'm making an app where the window is translucent using SvelteKit + Tauri.

I've tried setting the `transparent` to `true` in `tauri.conf.json` and the container element has a 0.92 opacity in css.

```json
// tauri.conf.json
"windows": [
    {
        "fullscreen": false,
        "height": 600,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "Pastato",
        "width": 800,
        "transparent": true
    }
]
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    padding: 1rem;

    background: rgba(41, 41, 41, 0.92);
}
```

This worked but not at the start. I had to resize the window to clear the flat color it gave me.
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a potential Tauri bug that should be reported if that has not happened already.

Comment: I see, will try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the window as a whole partially transparent, you might be able to use [`window-vibrancy`](https://github.com/tauri-apps/window-vibrancy) instead, which uses platform-specific functionalities for such an effect. (It is not available everywhere and may couple it to a blur effect, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround on Tauri's Discord server.

I need to set `decorations` to `false` and use the JS API to set it back to true later.

```json
"windows": [
    {
        "fullscreen": false,
        "height": 600,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "Pastato",
        "width": 800,
        "transparent": true,
        "decorations": false
    }
]
```

```
import { appWindow } from '@tauri-apps/api/window';
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

onMount(async () => {
    await appWindow.setDecorations(true);
});
```

Comment: That also looks more like a workaround that anything else 

Comment: Oh yeah it is. They said Windows doesn't really like when windows are transparent with decorations on. Same thing with Electron.

Comment: works for me, after set  "allowlist": { "all": true,}